# Does Oracle 10g database and GEO-Spacial search functionality

Tags: oracle10g, geospatial

Does Oracle 10g database have GEO-Spacial search functionality out of the box, or is it something that needs to be install as an addition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with geospatial technology, but this section from the [Oracle® Spatial User's Guide and Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_locator.htm#i632018) may be useful:

> Oracle Locator (also referred to as Locator) is a feature of Oracle
>   Database 10g Standard Edition. Locator provides core features and
>   services available in Oracle Spatial. It provides significant
>   capabilities typically required to support Internet and wireless
>   service-based applications and partner-based GIS solutions. Locator is
>   not designed to be a solution for geographic information system (GIS)
>   applications requiring complex spatial data management. If you need
>   capabilities such as linear referencing, spatial functions, or
>   coordinate system transformations, use Oracle Spatial instead of
>   Locator.
>
> Like Spatial, Locator is not designed to be an end-user application,
>   but is a set of spatial capabilities for application developers.
>
> Locator is available with both the Standard and Enterprise Editions of
>   Oracle Database 10g. Spatial is a priced option available only with
>   Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition. Spatial includes all Locator
>   features as well as other features that are not available with
>   Locator.